# Retrieving Postgresql autoinc value from view trigger with JSDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, triggers

I have a view with a trigger that executes on each insert. This trigger actually updates several other tables. Bellow is the pseudo code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_proc() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  _id int4;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (NEW.key) RETURNING id INTO _id;
    INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (DEFAULT,_id,NEW.field1,NEW.field2); 
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trg INSTEAD OF INSERT ON myview FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_proc();
```

table1 is actually having a column of type SERIAL that generates new ids on each insert. This id is used to create a row in table2.
Now, I'd like to retrieve the generated id from Java code. With a "regular" table, I'd use Statement.getGeneratedKeys(). But I can't get this to work with the view/trigger, as the returned ResultSet is empty.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You could use a function to insert the data that returns the appropriate values.